# Vite: resolve.alias - how to resolve paths?

Tags: javascript, vite

What can [resolve.alias](https://vitejs.dev/config/#resolve-alias) do? It doesn't resolve the path below:

```
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import path from 'path'

export default defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, '/src'),
    },
  }
})
```

In my HTML:

```
<img src="@/assets/images/sample-1.jpg">
```

Error in the browser Console:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/@/assets/images/sample-1.jpg 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
client:180 [vite] connecting...
client:202 [vite] connected.
```

Any ideas how to do it correctly?

Comment: * As a note for people coming these days, I think using @ as an alias is probably a bad idea as many npm packages now include @ as a prefix and so you'll need to work around that. Perhaps use ~ which for aspnet devs has always meant 'the root'.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

npm install @rollup/plugin-alias --save-dev

## or

yarn add -D @rollup/plugin-alias

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import alias from '@rollup/plugin-alias'
import { resolve } from 'path'

const projectRootDir = resolve(__dirname);

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    alias({
      entries: [
        {
          find: '@',
          replacement: resolve(projectRootDir, 'src')
        }
      ]
    })
  ],
  server: {
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: 10086, 
    open: false,
    cors: true, 
  },
  build: {
    outDir: 'dist',
  }
})
```

or

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import alias from '@rollup/plugin-alias'
import { resolve } from 'path'

const projectRootDir = resolve(__dirname);

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    alias(),
    vue()
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": resolve(projectRootDir, "src"),
    },
  },
  server: {
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: 10086,
    open: false, 
    cors: true, 
  },
  build: {
    outDir: 'dist',
  }
})
```

Answer (score 30):

Looks like no additional plugins needed (vite 3.1.0), configuration `vite.config.js`:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import * as path from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
...
    resolve: {
        alias: [
            { find: '@', replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src') },
        ],
    },
...
});
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
...
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"],
    },
...
  },
...
}
```

Also don't forget about linting, eslint also should know about aliases. Just install eslint plugin `eslint-import-resolver-alias` and define it in eslint config
`.eslintrc.js`

```
module.exports = {
...
    settings: {
        'import/resolver': {
            node: {
                extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.ts', '.d.ts'],
            },
            alias: {
                extensions: ['.vue', '.js', '.ts', '.scss', '.d.ts'],
                map: [
                    ['@/components', './src/components'],
                    ['@/pages', './src/pages'],
                    ['@/router', './src/router'],
                    ['@/store', './src/store'],
                    ['@/styles', './src/styles'],
                    ['@/types', './src/types'],
                    ['@/utils', './src/utils'],
                ],
            },
        },
    },
...
};
```

As you can see I defined aliases for every folder, it's because i got problem with alias for whole folder `src`, it throw error for packages started with `@` symbol - can't resolve package, but current way works well.

Comment: the config for tsconfig.json work also in jsconfig.json, in VS Code i had no need for the eslint.js config

Comment: Thanks, this has been very helpful, do you know how to activate IDE autocomplete for aliases? When I type `import "@..."`, the path autocomplete doesn't work.

Comment: I found out how to do it. I activated this  in the settings. `"javascript.suggest.paths": true` and `"typescript.suggest.paths": true`
![image](https://github.com/Subwaytime/vite-aliases/assets/74573675/4255fb02-d683-4678-81ad-3a5084f1c3a5)

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution for version 2.7.12 (my current) is to declare alias as an **array**:

```
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import path from 'path'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [ vue() ],
  resolve: {
    alias: [
      { find: '@', replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, './src') },
      { find: '@config', replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/config') },
      { find: '@plugins', replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/plugins') },
      { find: '@views', replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/views') },
      { find: '@mixins', replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/mixins') },
      { find: '@svg', replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/svg') },
      { find: '@models', replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/models') },
      { find: '@components', replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/components') },
    ]
  }
})
```

You can see the legal format when checking the type:

```
resolve?: ResolveOptions & {
  alias?: AliasOptions;
};
```

where AliasOptions is an **array** of aliases:

```
export declare type AliasOptions = readonly Alias[] | { [find: string]: string }
```

Answer (score 2):

It's exhausting to map all `@*`, so use regex

```
import { resolve, join } from 'path';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: [
      { find: /@(.*)/, replacement: join(resolve(__dirname, 'src'), "$1") }
    ]
  }
});
```

It finds every `import @(.*)` and replaces it with `__dirname/src/$1`, whereas `$1` is the matching group after `@`.

For your `tsconfig.json`, do similar:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "paths": {
            "@*": ["./src/*"]
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can declare these as an object, with keys and values, instead of resolving paths yourself.

A small example:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
  ..
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@components': '/src/components',
      '@hooks': '/src/hooks',
      '@util': '/src/util',
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: This only works if you chroot or your project lives in the root of your OS.